# Spring Expression Language adding timestamp

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-el

My program pulls articles from API using HTTP requests. To see which articles were pulled  already from the API, a timestamp is used. Now my problem is, my program should only pull articles within 3 days timeframe. And not more. i.e. It should not exceed the current timestamp. That means, like if the current time is Wednesday 14:00, then the articles from Monday, Tuesday until now(Wednesday 14:00) should be pulled.
The first chain here receives the last timestamp file,
My code is:

```
<int:channel id="timestampFile" />

    <int:chain input-channel="timestampFile" output-channel="timestampWithHeaders">
            <file:file-to-string-transformer delete-files="false" charset="UTF-8" />
        <int:header-enricher >
            <int:header name="beginTime" expression="payload" />
            <int:header name="endTime" expression="new Long(payload) + new Long(${abc.poll.frequency})" />
            <int:header name="offset" value="0"/>
        </int:header-enricher>
    </int:chain>
```

How can I check if the end time is 3 days from the begin time and should not exceed the current timestamp?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare the long values:

```
endTime < beginTime + 60000*60*24*3
```

Comment: By doing this it will only ensure that the end time is within 3 days frame from the begin time. However i should also check the timestamp from the file last-timestamp before making a request and adjust it if needed. If it's older than 3 days it has to be reset to now-3days. i.e. If the end timestamp is in the future it has to be decreased to the current timestamp. how can I do this?

Comment: How can the timestamp be in the future? You would probably need a custom SpEL function to manipulate the file timestamp.

Comment: Thank you. I wrote a function that restricts the result not to be bigger than current time.

Comment: Also I have a question. How can i compare directly using SpEL? I mean is there any way i can do, if endTime < beginTime + 60000*60*24*3 then only do expression="new Long(payload) + new Long(${abc.poll.frequency}).

Comment: Do i have to use filter expression for this?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you're asking, but if the header expression evaluates to `null`, the header is not added (in fact an existing header with that name will be removed).